# Is there a way to calculate the [within] standard deviation with only one set of data?

Tags: r, statistics, usage-statistics

I am trying to write a script in Rstudio to create a histogram which I usually make in minitab. (Right now we are sharing 1 minitab license on my team which is not very efficient since we use it a lot).

I am trying to calculate the [within] standard deviation. Looking at minitab's website for it's explanation of the calculation :

[minitab how to calculate std within](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/20/help-and-how-to/quality-and-process-improvement/capability-analysis/how-to/capability-sixpack/between-within-capability-sixpack/methods-and-formulas/methods/)

I'm not sure if the within standard deviation makes any sense with the data that I have. I do not have any subgroups that I am aware of, but if you know how to calculate the within standard deviation I would really appreciate some help!

Here is my [R histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mj2o.png) , and the equivalent [Minitab 6 pack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aib9P.png). And what I have on [github].[4](https://github.com/sroemersnappy/sixpack)

The only data I have as an input for both methods is below.

407 412 405 400 405 400 406 401 408 407 405 401 400 405 404 404 406 411 408 410 410 409 410 407 404 405 408 404 409 402 403 406 402 407 410 407 407 407 403 410 398 409 402 407 399 406 403 409 410 404 406 403 410 400 411

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: The data you posted does not show any grouping (e.g., some belong to group "A", some belong to group "B", etc.). For a single group, the formula for within-group variance is the same as the standard formula for sample variance.

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling that was the case

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer with *dplyr* to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73545529/computing-sd-in-multiple-columns-with-dplr).

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                b = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                c = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2))
df
```

Here is the example data frame:

```
  a  b c
1 1  6 1
2 2  7 1
3 3  8 2
4 4  9 2
5 5 10 2
```

Here is the solution:

```
df_2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(c) %>% 
  summarise(across(.cols = everything(), ~ sd(.x)), .groups = "keep")

df
```

Here is the output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   c [2]
      c     a     b
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 0.707 0.707
2     2 1     1
```

Familiarize yourself with `across` for any functions applied across multiple variables. `~ sd()` is a lambda function, which is like an inline function. `.x` represents the data you're transforming.