# Computing sd in multiple columns with dplr

Tags: r, statistics

Please help me calculate the sd in multiple columns of my df. In the case of the median and the mean with the same code, everything works fine.

```
median <- df_grouped_by %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, median) # works correctly
sd <- df_grouped_by %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, sd)
```

it receives the error:

```
Error in `summarise_if()`:
! `.funs` must be a one sided formula, a function, or a function name.
```

Data is grouped by grouping variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer with *dplyr*.

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                b = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                c = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2))
df
```

Here is the example data frame:

```
  a  b c
1 1  6 1
2 2  7 1
3 3  8 2
4 4  9 2
5 5 10 2
```

Here is the solution:

```
df_2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(c) %>% 
  summarise(across(.cols = everything(), ~ sd(.x)), .groups = "keep")

df
```

Here is the output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   c [2]
      c     a     b
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 0.707 0.707
2     2 1     1
```

Familiarize yourself with `across` for any functions applied across multiple variables. `~ sd()` is a lambda function, which is like an inline function. `.x` represents the data you're transforming.